# Fastest way to add values to the surface of a sphere in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array that represents my voxelgrid.. Now i want to add values to the surface of a sphere for a given radius. What is the fastest way? 
My solution:

```
def spheric Surface (x, y, z, r, value):
        while phi <= (2*math.pi):
            eta = math.pi * 2 / 3
            while eta <= math.pi:
                xx = x + r * math.sin(eta) * math.cos(phi)
                yy = y + r * math.sin(eta) * math.sin(phi)
                zz = z + r * math.cos(eta)
                xx = int(xx*resoultion+0.5)
                yy = int(yy*resolution+0.5)
                zz = int(zz*resolution+0.5)
                voxelGrid[xx][yy][zz] += value

                eta += 1/10 * math.pi
            phi += 1/10 * math.pi
```

This is my first Idea: It ist not very fast and not very accurate because with bigger r, i need more angle to calculate.., not just adding 1/10pi for example but 1/5pi, but this makes the code even slower... 
Resolution is the resolution of my voxelgrid.. so with Resolution 3, x=2mm would become xx= 6 in the array..
And yes i dont want the whole surface of the sphere, just from 2/3pi to pi...

Is there any better and faster way?

I tried the way with the mask like this, but it is even slower:

```
def sphericSurface(x, y, z, r, value):
    tol = 0.6

    grenz = math.pi * 2 / 3
    mask = (np.logical_and(np.logical_and((sx[:, None, None] - x) ** 2 + (sy[None, :, None] - y) ** 2 + (sz[None, None, :] - z) ** 2 <= (r + tol)**2,
                                          (sx[:, None, None] - x) ** 2 + (sy[None, :, None] - y) ** 2 + (sz[None, None, :] - z) ** 2 >= (r - tol)**2),
                           (sz[None, None, :] - z) <= (r*math.cos(grenz))))
    x, y, z = np.where(mask==True)
    z *= 2
    voxelGrid[x,y,z] += value
```

Comment: In computer graphics a common technique is to generate points by starting on a polygon (icosahedron, e.g) and subdivide a bunch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron

Comment: two minor things: you need an underscore in the name of your function, and why don't you index into voxelgrid like `voxelgrid[xx,yy,zz]`?

Comment: what positions correspond to the elements of your voxelgrid? What is resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can select all of the elements that require modification by generating a mask. I'm not sure how compatible this is which what you already have, but this is the way. It'll basically blow the doors off of the while loop solution speed-wise.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
z = np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
points = np.array(np.meshgrid(x,y,z)).T

def make_mask(points,a,b,c,r,tol=1e-2):
    """generates a boolean mask of positions within tol distance of the surface of the sphere
    (x-a)**2 + (y-b)**2 + (z-c)**2 = r**2"""
    mask = (points[...,0]-a)**2+(points[...,1]-b)**2+(points[...,2]-c)**2 < (r+tol)**2
    return mask

mask = make_mask(points,2.5,2.5,2.5,1.0,tol=0.2) 
# this will tell you all of the points in voxelgrid which need modification
voxelgrid[mask] #will return them all
```

If you want to add a value to every point near the surface of the sphere you can do

```
voxelgrid[mask]+=value
```

provided that the voxelgrid and points coordinates coincide in the sense that `voxelgrid[i,j,k]` is the container associated with the point `points[i,j,k]`.. you will have to use your `resolution` parameter to make the `x,y,z` so that this is true.

Here's a lame plot showing that it works for me:

[image]

The code for this plot is

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(*points[mask].T)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('works.png')
```

You can maybe calculate the mask more cleanly with something like:

```
x0 = np.array([a,b,c])
mask = np.sum((points-x0)**2,axis=-1)<(r+tol)**2
```

but it's a little harder to read. It may be faster ? I am not sure on this. (can anyone weigh in? )

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! One last question, how do i do that with the resolution? Lets say for example z has a resolution of 2. so the point 1,1,1 would be [1,1,2] in the voxelgrid?

Comment: Hey @Kevinkayaks I tested it but it is way slower than the method with the while loops..

Comment: I wonder if you're recalculating the mask every step you use it?

Comment: yes! i cannot use the same mask, since my r is not the same ? and also my x, y, z..  u have a better idea? Look how i did it in my question.. i added my try with mask..

Comment: Do your radii fall within a discrete set? You could generate all required masks once by the fastest method and then call them as needed.

Comment: ok yes i could create maybe a mask for every radius, but i think it would need a lot of memory and secon my x,y,z, coordinates will change?